# How do you avoid two mouseclick events registering from a div on top of another?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent, stoppropagation

JSFiddle [link to code](https://jsfiddle.net/wongx/p6b0y42r/40/)

The situation:

- I have click handlers on both a circle and a box.
- The circle is inside the box.
- When I click the box, it registers the box click.
- When I click the circle, it registers BOTH the box and circle click.

`event.stopPropagation()` and `event.cancelBubbles=true` aren't working, unless I'm using it incorrectly.

How can I avoid registering the box click when clicking the circle?

html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

const handleBox = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  console.log('box clicked');
};

const handleCircle = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  console.log('circle clicked');
}

box.addEventListener('click', handleBox);
circle.addEventListener('mousedown', handleCircle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is listening for a click on the box, but a mousedown on the circle.

Because of that, the circle gets a click, fails to catch it, and passes it up to the box.

The fix: change this:

```js
circle.addEventListener('mousedown', handleCircle);
```

to this:

```js
circle.addEventListener('click', handleCircle);
```

Comment: That was intentional but I changed it to be consistent and it fixed the issue. Silly thing to overlook by me, but thank you very much!